# How to cope with multi AZ RDS MySQL on SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, windows, amazon-web-services, high-availability

We run SQL Server (production), and RDS MySQL off AWS. Both have their respective *static* IP address. SQL Server pulls data from MySQL database regularly. If we enable multi AZ for the RDS MySQL instance, how then should we configure SQL Server?

Current configuration utilises MySQL Connector/ODBC Data Source Configuration and we believe that the TCP/IP Server field accepts only a valid IP address. It is *not* able to establish connection, although able to resolve the endpoint's IP address correctly, to the MySQL server. By endpoint, I mean the long connection string -- *myInstanceName.abbd12345.us-east1.rds.amazonaws.com*

[image: SQL Server's Server Objects> Linked Servers connection string config]

[image: MySQL Connector Data Source Configuration]

In an event of a MySQL failover, the endpoint string remains the same but its IP address would have changed/switched over to another. This, effectively, will render the current SQL Server configured connection by IP address to break. It will be a pain in the neck to update the connection by hand every time.

**TL;DL**
MySQL will be multi AZ. How to configure SQL Server to use the correct IP address if and when MySQL has a failover?

Comment: You should always use the DNS endpoint provided by RDS. The IP address on RDS is not static.

Comment: Duly noted. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, just found out that it does not work for MySQL ODBC driver v3.x. It **works** for MySQL ODBC driver version 5.x.

[image: Testing connection using full endpoint string on driver version 5.x]

Download the latest MySQL ODBC driver or version 5.x.
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html